# Spring boot tasks not completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on a spring boot application (deployed on aws elastic beanstalk) where there are some long running tasks that sometimes do not complete. I know they don't because I have a log before starting and after ending.
For example a task is getting a zip file with images and posting them on aws S3. Sometimes it stops before uploading all the images.
Another task is getting a csv or json file and updating data in the database, same problem.

I am wondering if this is due to some aws operations (auto scaling for example) or a performance of the vm issue

Example of code posting images to S3

```java
for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
saveLog("uploading " + (i+1) + ".JPG");
try {
    uploadedAutres += doUploadOneOfMultipleImages(product,
            ImageIO.read(zipFile.getInputStream(images.get(i))), i , false); //i + product.getNombreImagesAutre()
} catch (Throwable e) {
    saveLog("failed uploading " + (i+1) + ".JPG\n" + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    break;
}
}

public int doUploadOneOfMultipleImages(Product product, BufferedImage image, int i, boolean threeSixty) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream largeByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream mediumByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", largeByteArray);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImageExample.resize(image, 434, 650), "png", mediumByteArray);
            largeByteArray.close();
            mediumByteArray.close();

            String largeFileName = threeSixty ? "" : "autre/";
            String newFileName = threeSixty ? "" : "autre/";
            newFileName += product.getReference() + "/";
            largeFileName += product.getReference() + "/large_";
            if(i+1 <= 9) {
                newFileName += "0";
                largeFileName += "0";
            }
            newFileName += i+1;
            newFileName += ".jpg";
            largeFileName += i+1;
            largeFileName += ".jpg";
            objectOperations.upload(bucketName, newFileName, mediumByteArray.toByteArray(), "image/jpeg");
            objectOperations.upload(bucketName, largeFileName, largeByteArray.toByteArray(), "image/jpeg");
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

public void upload(String bucketName, String objectKey, byte[] objectBytes, String contentType) throws Exception {

        String result = putS3Object(s3Client, bucketName, objectKey, objectBytes, contentType);

    }
    public String putS3Object(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String objectKey, byte[] objectBytes, String contentType) throws Exception {
            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName)
                            .key(objectKey)
                            .contentType(contentType)
                            .build(),
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(objectBytes));
            return response.eTag();
    }
```

When it stops it's in the middle of the loop (for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)) and no exception is thrown

Comment: Is your Spring BOOT app invoking a workflow created in AWS Step functions. If you have many AWS operations that you want to invoke from a Spring BOOT app - that is one way to perform it

Comment: Nope everything is done in the app

Comment: SO you have a class in your Spring BOOT app that uses the AWS SDK for Java to invoke operations directly from your app. And you are seeing some of the AWS operations failing to complete? Are exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Yes I'm using the aws sdk and there are no exceptions. When this happens, I just reiterate the operation and it works.

Comment: Can you post Java code for an operation that sometimes shows this behavior? For example - lets see the code you use to post files from ZIP to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: I don't think it's a java problem because it works when I call it a second time

Comment: Ok thanks, but I must specify that it works most of the time, I have no Idea why sometimes it doesn't complete

Comment: my upload method calls s3.putObject

Comment: This could absolutely be caused by auto-scaling. You can look at the auto scaling history in your account to see if a scale-in action occurred during the time of one of these failures.

Comment: See this topic for more info on auto scaling - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html

Comment: @smac2020 I'm using version 2.13.21

Comment: @MarkB is there a way to avoid this auto scaling or plan it to when the app is not being used ?

Comment: Thxs for clarifying. At 1st thought it was a 3rd party API not recognizing the code . Looks like your issue could be related to EB settings As Mark pointed out.

Comment: I think I'm gonna switch to ec2 instead of EB :D

Comment: Have you confirmed auto-scaling is the issue? A more fault-tolerant solution would be to queue up these tasks in AWS SQS, and then have your service process the tasks. That way if a server is replaced the task it was working on would go back in the queue and get picked up by the next server. Auto-scaling itself isn't a bad thing, and it actually provides fault tolerance for your server, so you shouldn't stop using it because of this issue. Instead you should design your application with cloud services in mind.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about SQS, gonna look for it